# Inconsistent Error/ Exception, Codec not found for requested operation: [float <-> java.lang.Object] and [int <-> java.lang.Object]

Tags: cassandra, annotations, guava, datastax-java-driver

I am having CodecNotFoundException with the below stacktrace, while trying to 
insert data using annotations of datastax java driver for mapping with cassandra.

**Exception 1::**

```
Exception in thread "main" com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.CodecNotFoundException: Codec not found for requested operation: [float <-> java.lang.Object]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.CodecNotFoundException.copy(CodecNotFoundException.java:56)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.CodecNotFoundException.copy(CodecNotFoundException.java:25)
    at com.datastax.driver.mapping.DriverThrowables.propagateCause(DriverThrowables.java:41)
    at com.datastax.driver.mapping.Mapper.save(Mapper.java:275)
    at com.coreanalytics.componentConfig.ChartConfigInteraction.saveChartConf(ChartConfigInteraction.scala:14)
    at com.coreanalytics.componentConfig.testing$.delayedEndpoint$com$coreanalytics$componentConfig$testing$1(ChartConfigInteraction.scala:23)
    at com.coreanalytics.componentConfig.testing$delayedInit$body.apply(ChartConfigInteraction.scala:18)
    at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:35)
    at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:76)
    at com.coreanalytics.componentConfig.testing$.main(ChartConfigInteraction.scala:18)
    at com.coreanalytics.componentConfig.testing.main(ChartConfigInteraction.scala)
```

**Exception 2::**

```
Exception in thread "main" com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.CodecNotFoundException: Codec not found for requested operation: [int <-> java.lang.Object]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.CodecNotFoundException.copy(CodecNotFoundException.java:56)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.CodecNotFoundException.copy(CodecNotFoundException.java:25)
    at com.datastax.driver.mapping.DriverThrowables.propagateCause(DriverThrowables.java:41)
    at com.datastax.driver.mapping.Mapper.save(Mapper.java:275)
    at com.coreanalytics.componentConfig.ChartConfigInteraction.saveChartConf(ChartConfigInteraction.scala:14)
    at com.coreanalytics.componentConfig.testing$.delayedEndpoint$com$coreanalytics$componentConfig$testing$1(ChartConfigInteraction.scala:23)
    at com.coreanalytics.componentConfig.testing$delayedInit$body.apply(ChartConfigInteraction.scala:18)
    at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:35)
    at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:76)
    at com.coreanalytics.componentConfig.testing$.main(ChartConfigInteraction.scala:18)
    at com.coreanalytics.componentConfig.testing.main(ChartConfigInteraction.scala)
```

The problem is I am getting this two different exception when try to execute the same code. (same table, same insert operation, no change) (e.g. for first time execution I get exception with `float` and than second or third time I got with the `int` one)
I have checked my table twice, it doesn't seem there is any issue with types, but than why I am getting this exception ?

As my table having around 50 columns with around 8 UDTs it is difficult to show the whole schema here. I also verified UDTs field type with beans' properties. And ya, I am using `Scala` do all these stuffs.

**Note:** I have tried updating `Guava` dependency but It has problem with FutureCallBack as it is removed.

Answer (score 1):

The CodecNotFoundException is thrown if the cql type does not match the type of the java attribute that should be mapped.

See the following links:

- http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.1/manual/
- http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.1/manual/object_mapper/using/
- http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.1/manual/object_mapper/custom_codecs/

This seems to be a similar questions:
[Datastax Cassandra Driver throwing CodecNotFoundException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37588733/datastax-cassandra-driver-throwing-codecnotfoundexception)

Comment: @Phillip I have gone through these links. I learned mapping from these docs and following it in my app, still I am having this issue. I also applied mapping in other tables and its working as expected in same app.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to me a simple "binding" problem. As the error clearly says, you are binding an int/float field to an object and the driver can't make that association because it doesn't know how to do it.

The fix is simple, you must ensure that each CF gets its association done right at application level.

If you can't understand when it fails put your table definition here (even if it's huge), and remember to post here also the code that binds data to columns.

Comment: I know it should be binding problem but I checked twice. And even if there is mistake in binding, why it shows different exception? And my table schema have 8 UDTs, I don't mind but you think I should post here 9 table schema and 9 bean classes??