# Enum as value type in Map in Spring-data-cassandra

Tags: java, spring, dictionary, enums, cassandra

In spring-data-cassandra, how can I use an Enum inside a Map in one of my entities. E.g.

```
public class User implements Serializable {
  private Map<String, LanguageLevel> languageToLevelMap;

  // getters and setters omitted
}
```

Here, LanguageLevel is an Enum.

```
public enum LanguageLevel {
  GOOD,
  BAD
}
```

The result is

```
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.CodecNotFoundException: Codec not found for requested operation: [ANY <-> de.test.LanguageLevel]
```

Answer (score 0):

first create enums like this

```
public enum LangEnums { LANGUAGELEVEL}
```

and then create HasMap Like This

```
Map <String, Enum>  mapWithEnums=new HashMap<>()
mapWithEnums.put("Test", LANGUAGELEVEL)
```

Comment: Hi Zak, thanks for the comment. However, thats more or less what I do and what leads to the above exception, the moment i try to store the entity in Cassandra.

Comment: This might help   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37588733/datastax-cassandra-driver-throwing-codecnotfoundexception